# Hazelcast error since upgrading JBoss to wildfly in Solaris 11.1 environment

Tags: jboss, solaris, hazelcast

Since we have moved from JBoss 6 to either JBoss 7 or wildfly 10 with our application we see the following error:

```
05:47:26,696 ERROR [com.hazelcast.spi.OperationService] (hz.GMP-HZ [2126@arod].response) [127.0.0.1]:5701 [gmp1@arod] [3.2.1] While processing response...: com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: No call for response:NormalResponse\{callId=2, urgent=true, value=false, backupCount=0}
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationService$ResponseProcessor.notifyRemoteCall(BasicOperationService.java:804)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationService$ResponseProcessor.run(BasicOperationService.java:817)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.SingleExecutorThreadFactory$ManagedThread.run(SingleExecutorThreadFactory.java:45)

05:47:26,718 WARN  [com.hazelcast.partition.InternalPartitionService] (hz.GMP-HZ [2126@arod].global-operation.thread-52) [127.0.0.1]:5702 [gmp1@arod] [3.2.1] This is the master node and received a PartitionRuntimeState from Address[127.0.0.1]:5701. Ignoring incoming state!
05:47:26,719 ERROR [com.hazelcast.partition.InternalPartitionService] (hz.GMP-HZ [2126@arod].global-operation.thread-46) [127.0.0.1]:5703 [gmp1@arod] [3.2.1] Received a ClusterRuntimeState from an unknown member! => Sender: Address[127.0.0.1]:5701, Master: Address[127.0.0.1]:5702!
05:47:26,747 WARN  [com.hazelcast.partition.InternalPartitionService] (hz.GMP-HZ [2126@arod].global-operation.thread-33) [127.0.0.1]:5704 [gmp1@arod] [3.2.1] Received a ClusterRuntimeState, but its sender doesn't seem to be master! => Sender: Address[127.0.0.1]:5702, Master: Address[127.0.0.1]:5701! (Ignore if master node has changed recently.)
```

This is running on Solaris 11.1 SPARC. On Red Hat Linux it is fine. Any help with this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Mind posting full logs and Hazelcast config?